# Handle builtin commands

Tags: c, shell, unix, posix

I've written a small C function to handle the builtin commands of a [custom shell](https://github.com/montao/openshell) that I'm writing in C. Is it better to use a switch instead?

```
int handleBuiltinCommands(char *input, int ret) {
    int built_in_command = 0;
    if (strcmp(input, "exit") == 0) {
        free(input);
        exit(0);
    }
    if (StartsWith(input, "cd")) {
        built_in_command = 1;
        runcd(input);
    }
    if (StartsWith(input, "checkEnv")) {
        built_in_command = 1;
        checkEnv(ret);
    }
    return built_in_command;
}
```

I compile it with `gcc -pedantic -Wall -ansi -O3`

(Background: [Tokenizing a shell command](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125820/tokenizing-a-shell-command))

Comment: You *cannot* `switch` over strings in C so the question whether doing so would be better is somewhat moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK to use the `if` construction, although if you plan to have more than a few commands, using `switch` leads to cleaner code imho. In addition, why not using `if else` instead of just `if`? That way not all of your `if` have to be evaluated (in average).

Comment: The code is in C, so `switch` can't be used on strings, c.f. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014827/best-way-to-switch-on-a-string-in-c) for some ideas around it.

Comment: Ow, that's right.